# VBA/Excel Error with Find: Object variable not set or type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba, object, visio, mismatch

In this macro I'm extracting network data from Visio and putting it into an excel file.  In the visio file there are objects which may show up multiple times, but I only want these items listed once in the excel file.  So, before inputting a new entry the macro first searches the range of data previously recorded.  The error comes in the .Find command.  The frustrating thing is that the macro will run once and then fail upon subsequent runs. But if I reset it, it will run once more.  I actually tried two slightly different ways of doing the search.  The first method resulted in a "object variable with block variable not set" error.  The 2nd method resulted in a "type-mismatch" error.   Here is the relevant portion of code (Error section with **)

```
Dim oXLApp As Excel.Application
Dim oXLBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim oXLSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Set oXLApp = New Excel.Application    'Create a new instance of Excel
oXLApp.Visible = True
Dim iSheetsPerBook As Integer         'Add a new workbook (with one sheet)
iSheetsPerBook = oXLApp.SheetsInNewWorkbook
oXLApp.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 4
Set oXLBook = oXLApp.Workbooks.Add
oXLApp.SheetsInNewWorkbook = iSheetsPerBook
Set oXLSheet = oXLBook.Worksheets(1) 
Dim CurrentTrans As String
Dim RangeObj As Range

Application.ActiveWindow.SelectAll
Dim RowCounter As Integer
Dim ColCounter As Integer
Dim NeededSpaces As Integer
RowCounter = 1

For x = 1 To ActiveWindow.Selection.Count 'iterate all selected shapes
    Dim vsoshape As Visio.shape
    Dim vsoShapetype As String
    Set vsoshape = ActiveWindow.Selection(x) 'activate next selected shape

    If Not vsoshape Is Nothing Then
        If InStr(vsoshape.Name, "Circle") > 0 Then
          Dim lngOutGoingShapeIDs() As Long
          Dim lngIncomingShapeIDs() As Long
          lngOutGoingShapeIDs = vsoshape.ConnectedShapes(visConnectedShapesOutgoingNodes, "")
          lngIncomingShapeIDs = vsoshape.ConnectedShapes(visConnectedShapesIncomingNodes, "")

          Dim NewTrans As Integer  'Flag to show if Transition is new (=1) or was previously listed (=0)
          NewTrans = 1             ' Reset flag to 1, assumes transition is new
          ColCounter = 2                ' Reset ColCounter to 2

          If Not IsEmpty(oXLSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value) Then  'Previous Firing Data Exists, Must check listed transitions to avoid duplication
            oXLSheet.Range("A1", oXLSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Select
            CurrentTrans = vsoshape.Text
            Debug.Print CurrentTrans
            **Set RangeObj = Selection.Find(What:=CurrentTrans, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)**
            If RangeObj Is Nothing Then   'This is a new tranisition with no previous Firing data listed
                oXLSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Activate
                RowCounter = ActiveCell.Row + 1
```

The error is in the 'Set RangeObj ...'.  In this instance, the macro will run successfully once.  But subsequent attempts give an "Object variable with block variable not set" error.  If vba is reset it will run once again.  If I instead Set RangeObj as follows I get a "Run-time error 13 type-mismatch".

```
   Set RangeObj = oXLSheet.Range("A1", oXLSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Find(What:=CurrentTrans, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
```

As with the previous problem, this will run once and then fail with an error at this step until the macro is reset.  I checked the "CurrentTrans" variable that I'm searching for, and it is always a string.  I have it set to view the excel sheet and the range to be searched always contains strings.

This is exceedingly frustrating, so any help will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you doing this from vba-visio?

Comment: BTW you might be able to get away with the error using this `After:=oXLSheet.ActiveCell` But I would recommend not to use `Select`, `Selection`, `Activecell`, `Activate` etc. See [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select/10718179#10718179)

Comment: Yes, I am doing this from Visio, and yes, I am learning that Select, ActiveCell, etc. are problematic, hence the change to the second option.  Forgot about the After:=ActiveCell though.  I'll go back through the whole code and swap everything out for complete references and see if that helps.  Thanks.

Comment: @RBarryYoung,  No the error occurs with the Set RangeObj line as stated.  This is the line that is highlighted by VBA when I get the error message.  The macro will run completely through (completing all necessary loop iterations) without any errors one time.  Then if I re-run the macro a 2nd time, I get the error.  If I then reset the macro, it will again run to completion without error.

Comment: OK, yes, it's probably the Select/ActiveCell stuff.  They are very problematice because of all of the unobvious (and even undocumented) interactions they have.  For instance, IIRC, the `Find` feature of Excel implements some of its functionality visually, and leaves certain intermediate states in the GUI (that would naturally change the behavior of any immediates Select/ActiveCell type calls.)

Comment: @SiddharthRout, Yep that was the problem.  I now have it as `After:=oXLSheet.Range("A1")` (my search string should never appear in that 1st cell, so I'm ok ending there).  Now my error has moved to the next instance of `ActiveCell` ... fun times learning vba, yay microsoft!

Comment: @agnuke: honestly, you don't need `After:=` Did you see my answer below? If you also notice that there is no use of `Select`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. (UNTESTED)

```
'
'~~> Rest of the code
'

Dim Lrow As Long
Dim rngF As Range

With oXLSheet
    Lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rngF = .Range("A1:A" & Lrow)
End With

CurrentTrans = vsoshape.Text

Set RangeObj = rngF.Find(What:=CurrentTrans, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

'
'~~> Rest of the code
'
```